Являются ли придаточные предложения однородными?
Эти несчастные отдают за амулет последние деньги, потому что верят, что на них снизойдёт благодать(,) и однажды они станут богатыми.
Являются ли придаточные изъяснительные "на них снизойдёт благодать" и "однажды они станут богатыми" однородными? Соответственно, нужно ли ставить перед союзом "и" запятую?

Правильно:
Эти несчастные отдают за амулет последние деньги, потому что верят, что на них снизойдёт благодать и (что) однажды они станут богатыми.
Пояснение
Изъяснительные придаточные всегда однородны, так как они относятся к одному опорному слову верят в главном предложении. Дополнительный смысловой анализ не нужен.

• Благодать
1. По представлениям христиан: благо или изобилие благ, ниспосланные свыше; Божья помощь, покровительство. "Слово о законе и благодати" митрополита Илариона.
2. Разг. О чём-либо очень хорошем, доставляющем наслаждение, радость и т. п. Не жизнь, а благодать. От такой благодати и уезжать не хочется.
3. в функц. сказ. Высок. О состоянии покоя, умиротворённости (природы, окружающего мира или человека). На душе у него благодать.
Благодать — понятие обширное, емкое, "разноплановое", и у каждого оно свое.
У кого суп жидкий, а у кого жемчуг мелкий.
• Я думаю, что придаточные являются однородными, поэтому запятая перед и не нужна.
Нашелся и, как мне кажется, подходящий пример (У. С. Моэм. Узорный покров):

Помните, исполнять возложенные на вас обязанности – это еще мало, это не более похвально, чем омыть руки, когда они грязные. Что действительно важно – это исполнять свой долг с любовью. Когда долг и любовь будут слиты воедино, вот тогда на вас снизойдет благодать и вы познаете радость несказанную.

Сложноподчинённые предложения с несколькими придаточными
